# How can i see my Windows PC from Ubuntu?

Tags: samba, shared-folders, mate

I recently installed Ubuntu MATE 15.04 and even before I installed Samba I had full access to my Windows PC in my home network. even watching a shared movie via VLC player worked.

Then I installed Samba and I have access to the Windows PC and shared files...  After two or three days I can't locate my PC from Ubuntu.
I have tried several times of uninstall and reinstall of Samba and even used the command to restart but nothing helped me.

*How should I get access from my Ubuntu to that Windows PC?*

Answer (score 1):

A samba server is to allow your Windows PC to see the files on your Ubuntu PC, not to allow your PC so see the Windows files.  So if you only want to see the files from Ubuntu on the Windows PC, just uninstall Samba and its configuration by  pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge samba
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then install the client only:

```
apt-get install smbclient
```

Open Nautilus and you can browse the Windows network...

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: o_O Are you sure? I need samba to view files in a Windows network.

Comment: Answer edited after comment!  ;-)  Thanks for reminding me that the client needs to be installed.